# Войти на маяк или войти в маяк

Tags: управление

Подскажите, пожалуйста, войти на маяк или войти в маяк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба варианта неудачны - по разным причинам. А для выбора правильного не хватает контекста.

Я дополню имеющийся ответ.

Совершенно верно, маяк - башня, ***в*** которую можно ***войти***, и ***на*** которую можно ***взойти*** (не войти).

Но тут черт, как всегда - в деталях. Маяк как место требует предлога "на" (Работал на маяке), маяк как устройство - "в" (копался в неисправном маяке). В таких случая вариант "вошел в" лучше не использовать. При этом совсем не исключается вариант "пришел на маяк", не означающий физического входа в знание.

Сравните: пришел на завод, вошел в здание завода.
Мораль: выбирать надо между "вошел в здание" и "взошел на маяк" с учетом контекста.

Answer (score 1):

"Взойти на маяк".

Или "войти в здание маяка".

Comment: пишите подробнее